# CakePHP: best way to remove a field from the admin scaffold

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

When I admin-scaffold the Users model, everything works great. However, it also has the "password" field. Which is a hash of the actual password.

When you save a user in the admin console, it saves the hashed password, which screws everything up.

What's the simplest way to exclude a field from the admin-scaffold with minimal interference to the awesome auto-magic of the admin-scaffold?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't bake your code using (custom) bake templates when going "productive"? scaffolding as such is usually just for prototyping until the database layer stabilizes enough to start baking solid files.
But besides that you might be interesting in my proposals for cake2.4 regarding $skipFields: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1920-enhancements-for-bake-templates (could also be applied to your case).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am not ready to bake yet. But I think your proposal for skipping fields in bake is good.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make your own bake theme, so you can then edit the template to remove the file.

It really is as simple as this, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html#modify-default-html-produced-by-baked-templates

Just copy the files from inside `lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/views` into your project under `app/Console/Templates/[themename]/views` and then you can edit the view templates.

The same applies to all the other files too, such as controllers and models. Then when you bake your project you'll be asked which theme you want to use and you can select your own.

Here is an example from one of my projects.

[image]

The only real thing to note is that your theme names must be unique!